# Mishlei Proverbs 16:4

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, commentaries, translation, mishlei

I found some different translations of Mishlei 16:4. On the chabad.org website it is translated as:

> 'The Lord made everything for **His praise** - even the wicked man for the
>   day of evil'

While the mechon-mamre.org website reads:

> The Lord hath made every things for **His own purpose**...

The JPS translation reads:

> The Lord made everything for a / **it's purpose**...

So how should the words כל פעל יהוה למענהו be translated and understand, what does it mean?

Comment: It seems to me that the root for למענהו is the same as in למען, so I think "purpose" is a better translation, IMO.

Comment: @ezra His or it's purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Rashi and [Metsudat David](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA) there, as well as [Rabbenu Bahya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bahya_ben_Asher) (Leviticus 5:1), it means that God made everything for His praise.

According to [Ralbag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gersonides) (Proverbs 16:1) it means that God created everything for a purpose. Unlike [Rashi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashi), he understands למענהו to mean *its purpose*; not *His purpose* (or praise). This is also the implication of [Rabbenu Avraham ben Sh'lomo](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%94%D7%9D_%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%94_(%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9F)) (I Samuel 21: p. 272).

Comment: Thank you so much; so one could say 'for His purpose' is some a kind of combination between these two views. Good to know this.