Does God cause people to sin?
Is the following statement within the pale of orthodox Judaism?: "As the First Cause God wills everything that happens in the universe and thus predestines all humans to their degree of righteousness or wickedness."
Edit: I am just asking about God's role.  Whether or not this is compatible with free will is a different question. This is also not the question about foreknowledge because a prophet could know what someone will do in the future as well, so the real issue is not knowing the future but being the First Cause.

God's will is that we have free will. Also, who said anything about "eternal gehenna"?

@RabbiKaii  But does God decide who will be good and who will be evil?

See this question, very similar to yours, and the pasuk it quotes https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/139942/31534

@RabbiKaii So I take it the answer is yes?

God gives us the ability to choose to do good or evil. See Deutoronomy 30

This is mamash a general question about free will, which is a common theme with many mechalchkim: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37079/what-does-it-mean-that-god-hardened-pharaoh-s-heart

@wmasse the answer is look at the commentaries there and see what they say, paying attention to the limits and boundaries of their statements - most answers are partial answers

@Shimshon Done.

There is a general working answer that is "followed" by "many" today, to whatever end one can be said to "follow" a hashkafa, and I don't have estimates on numbers and percentages, but I do know that many in the Chareidi world, including Chabad, consider this the Jewish take on this question. This is the crux of the Tanya, for example, and the schools of thought that stem from the Zohar, and beyond.
The way it works is, every person is given a specific mission in life, and one major component of that mission, for most people, is one's work with one's own yeitzer hara. There are 2 things you need to know about this:

Each has their own unique yeitzer hara
There are 2 categories (broken in to further sub-categories, up to 5 depending on how you count) for achievement in this arena

Regarding 1, a person's unique yeitzer hara corresponds to a specific, unique set of illicit behaviours, and the reason a person is tempted by those behaviours, is because it gives them pleasure. Their job is to avoid performing those activities, and tame the passion for them.
Regarding 2, some achievements can be total, permanent victories, and some are lifetime's work:

Regarding the lifetime's work category, there are some who are all-but-destined to succumb and perform the illicit activities, and their job is to never give up, and work hard to still try to tame their yeitzer hara, by doing teshuva and doing their best to limit the activity, and even conquer it one day. The conquest, however, will be a ceasefire, rather than a victory, as they will always be tempted. The other group in this category never sin, but are also, always tempted.
Regarding the total victory category, some are able to actually tame their passions for only good. Some of us can do this on an individual level, for specific temptations, and very few people achieve the ability to do it for all their temptations, with Hashem's help.

This brings us to the last 2 cases. Someone born a Tzaddik, and someone born a total Rasha. Some people are indeed born without any temptation, and some are born destined to be wicked tyrants, like Hitler, y'sh. This is ok, because exceptions to rules is an acceptable Torah principle, and if one delves into the reasons offered by the commentaries for both of these categories, one will nonetheless encounter some resolutions like:

A Tzaddik does have free will still, and free will takes on a different form without a yeitzer hara (we will have free will in the days of Moshiach). This might also be true of certain Rashaim, like Haman.
There is a principle that Hashem takes away free will from leaders, in order to be the Master of History.
It's not always a total statement. Most of us are in a state of victory on some behaviours, ceasefire on others, and still struggling to stop doing yet others.

It turns out that the question of free will leads to a very rich tapestry of a picture, which is a global human mission that Hashem has tasked us, which has a zoomed in version of our own life story and free will, and relationship with Hashem, as well as the macroscopic picture of the entire Human Spirit - each of us with our little corner of the "human life force" that we are all individually working on, battling our yeitzer hara, for the benefit of all of humanity. The rewards of this will be revealed at a later time, when we are able to see what we achieved, and note that the Jewish people have been given the Torah, which means we have taken on full responsibility for this task, and will guarantee it is fully achieved, with Hashem's help, in time for Moshiach.
tl;dr: Most people have definitely got free will, but one does have to understand that Hashem tests man, and this leads to interesting things like "destined/very very likely to sin" etc. Some people seem like either exceptions, or special edges cases. It's a vast topic, get learning!

OP mentioned "in order to manifest His attribute of justice". I think regarding that aspect of the question, the answer is no?

@Chani I think that's a very deep statement, and it's hard to give a blanket "no" (Hashem's testing of us reveals the magnificence of his gevura, and gevura is a much more powerful force of attraction in a relationship than chesed), but it's obviously more complicated than that, which I hope those who read my answer and study the sources will slowly absorb and integrate. I also didn't tackle the "eternal gehinom" question, because while I don't believe in that, it is dealt with elsewhere
